# Shuffle Array from Collection

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, shuffle

I want to shuffel an array. But it will not work. This is my Query in Laravel

```
$spielerArray = Spieler::join('PlanungSpieler', 'PlanungSpieler.Player_ID', '=', 'Spieler.Player_ID')
            ->select('Spieler.Player_ID')->get();
```

And in the next step I want only shuffle the column Spieler.Player.

```
$finalShuffleResult = shuffle($spielerArray->Player_ID)
```

I get `Player_ID Instance does not exist on this collection`
Here is a part of my collection

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Spieler Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => Spieler
                    [connection:protected] => mysql
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [keyType:protected] => int
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [withCount:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [exists] => 1
                    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [Player_ID] => 101
                        )
```

How can I get Player_ID with the goal to shuffle them?

Comment: [`inRandomOrder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) might work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this
`$finalShuffleResult = $spielerArray->pluck('Player_ID')->shuffle()->all();`

Comment: Is it  the method of array_collection?

Comment: I've tested, it's working, it's a collection method (method for collection), just use it